# How to stop the cron job in golang while if condition is false?

Tags: go, cron, go-gin

I'm making a cron job for monitoring the data continuously. In the cron job function there is a condition on which I want to stop the cron job but I don't know how I will shut down the cron job. Below is the function I'm using :-

`CronController.go`

```
 func AutomaticChargedCron(c *gin.Context) {
     err:= //there is function which gives the value to err 
     if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("There is something wrong please try again later.", err)     
        //I want to stop the cron here
     } 
 }
```

`cron.go`

```
package cron

import (
    "gopkg.in/robfig/cron.v2"
)
func RunCron() {
    c := cron.New()

    c.AddFunc("@every 0h10m0s", AutomaticChargedCron)
    c.Start()
}

func AutomaticChargedCron() {
    utils.ExecuteCommand("sh " + config.GetBasePath() + "sh/charged.sh") 
}
```

`charged.sh`

```
 curl "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/charged"
```

`Router.go`

```
 func main() {
   router := gin.Default()

   router.GET("/charged", controllers.AutomaticChargedCron)

   router.Run()
   router.Run(":8080") 
}
```

I used `c.Stop()` but gives error

> c.Stop undefined (type *gin.Context has no field or method Stop)

Can anybody tell me about this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because the variable name `c` is used twice, one for cron job and other as `*gin.Contex` inside the handler function.

it can be mitigated with simple variable renaming.

```
cr := cron.New()
# and rename all occurrence of cron `c` as `cr`
cr.Stop()
```

#### Update

the renaming is necessary only if you are trying to use the cron `c` inside a handler function which uses the `(c *gin.Contex)`. The `c` in the function parameter shadows the global cron `c`.

Comment: Isn't the `c *gin.Context` variable local to the `AutomaticChargedCron` function i.e. it should not cause collusion with the cron initialization or do I miss something?

Comment: yes `c` is local to the `AutomaticChargedCron` function and you are trying to stop cron using the same variable `c` inside the same function `AutomaticChargedCron` so it will use the `*gin.Context` `c` not the `cron` `c`